# Google OAuth 2.0 for desktop apps for Windows without Admin privileges

Tags: google-oauth

I've heard about Google's plan of modernizing OAuth interactions described here: https://developers.googleblog.com/2016/08/modernizing-oauth-interactions-in-native-apps.html

Then I was looking at the sample desktop application for Windows found here: https://github.com/googlesamples/oauth-apps-for-windows/tree/master/OAuthDesktopApp.

It's pretty simple and it was working, but once I started Visual Studio without elevated privileges (as a non-admin), I experienced that the HttpListener was not able to start because of the following error: "Access Denied".

It turned out that starting an HttpListener at the loopback address (127.0.0.1) is not possible without admin rights. However trying localhost instead of 127.0.0.1 lead to success.

I found that there is a specific command that allows HttpListener to start at the given address (and port):

`netsh http add urlacl url=http://+:80/MyUri user=DOMAIN\user`

But it also can be only executed with admin rights, so it's not an option.

Still localhost seems to be the best shot but **OAuth 2.0 for Mobile & Desktop Apps** states the following regarding this section:

> See the redirect_uri parameter definition for more information about the loopback IP address. It is also possible to use localhost in place of the loopback IP, but this may cause issues with client firewalls. Most, but not all, firewalls allow loopback communication.

This is why I'm a bit suspicious to use localhost. So I'm wondering what is the recommended way of Google in this case, as I'm not intending to run our application as administrator just for this reason.

Any ideas?

Comment: I'm also very interested in the answer of this question.

Answer (score 0):

You can use TcpListener for instance instead of HttpListener. It does not need elevation to listen.

The following is a modified excerpt of this sample:
https://github.com/googlesamples/oauth-apps-for-windows/tree/master/OAuthDesktopApp

```
// Generates state and PKCE values.
string state = randomDataBase64url(32);
string code_verifier = randomDataBase64url(32);
string code_challenge = base64urlencodeNoPadding(sha256(code_verifier));
const string code_challenge_method = "S256";

// Creates a redirect URI using an available port on the loopback address.
var listener = new TcpListener(IPAddress.Loopback, 0);
listener.Start();
string redirectURI = string.Format("http://{0}:{1}/", IPAddress.Loopback, ((IPEndPoint)listener.LocalEndpoint).Port);
output("redirect URI: " + redirectURI);

// Creates the OAuth 2.0 authorization request.
string authorizationRequest = string.Format("{0}?response_type=code&scope=openid%20profile&redirect_uri={1}&client_id={2}&state={3}&code_challenge={4}&code_challenge_method={5}",
    authorizationEndpoint,
    System.Uri.EscapeDataString(redirectURI),
    clientID,
    state,
    code_challenge,
    code_challenge_method);

// Opens request in the browser.
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(authorizationRequest);

// Waits for the OAuth authorization response.
var client = await listener.AcceptTcpClientAsync();

// Read response.
var response = ReadString(client);

// Brings this app back to the foreground.
this.Activate();

// Sends an HTTP response to the browser.
WriteStringAsync(client, "<html><head><meta http-equiv='refresh' content='10;url=https://google.com'></head><body>Please close this window and return to the app.</body></html>").ContinueWith(t =>
{
    client.Dispose();
    listener.Stop();

    Console.WriteLine("HTTP server stopped.");
});

// TODO: Check the response here to get the authorization code and verify the code challenge
```

The read and write methods being:

```
private string ReadString(TcpClient client)
{
    var readBuffer = new byte[client.ReceiveBufferSize];
    string fullServerReply = null;

    using (var inStream = new MemoryStream())
    {
        var stream = client.GetStream();

        while (stream.DataAvailable)
        {
            var numberOfBytesRead = stream.Read(readBuffer, 0, readBuffer.Length);
            if (numberOfBytesRead <= 0)
                break;

            inStream.Write(readBuffer, 0, numberOfBytesRead);
        }

        fullServerReply = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(inStream.ToArray());
    }

    return fullServerReply;
}

private Task WriteStringAsync(TcpClient client, string str)
{
    return Task.Run(() =>
    {
        using (var writer = new StreamWriter(client.GetStream(), Encoding.UTF8))
        {
            writer.Write("HTTP/1.0 200 OK");
            writer.Write(Environment.NewLine);
            writer.Write("Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8");
            writer.Write(Environment.NewLine);
            writer.Write("Content-Length: " + str.Length);
            writer.Write(Environment.NewLine);
            writer.Write(Environment.NewLine);
            writer.Write(str);
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

By default there is a URL pattern `http://+:80/Temporary_Listen_Addresses/` which is allowed for all users (`\Everyone`)

You can use this as a prefix for your listener. More generally (to avoid collisions with other listeners) you should generate a URL under Temporary_Listen_Addresses (e.g. using a GUID) and use that as your listener prefix.

Unfortunately, a sysadmin can use `netsh http` to delete this entry or to restrict its usage to only certain users. Also, this does not appear to support listening for an HTTPS request as there is no corresponding ACL entry for port 443.

An admin can list all these permitted URL patterns using `netsh http show urlacl` as a command.